# Apache 2.4.12 & CentOS 7: DSO shared modules not being built during compile

Tags: centos, apache-2.4

I have a general question. I am attempting to compile Apache 2.4.12 on CentOS 7 from source. I have read the 2.4 documentation, poured over configure -h, and searched the web, but no one seems to be having the same issue as me. Trust me, I've tried many --enable-XXX=shared and other ./configure peculiarities and they all result in no DSOs being created! I am getting no configure or make errors at all. Any ideas?

Comment: I have used too many ./configure --blah combinations to make posting them useful. Either you've had this problem, or you have not.

Answer (score 0):

(From my install script)

General answer: Either The order of the configure options matters, or Apache does not like getting its --options on separate lines. Lead with enable-mods-shared like so (although, you may wany "few" or "reallyall", etc..)

```
cd httpd-2.4.12/
mkdir -v srclib/apr/ srclib/apr-util/
mv -v ../apr-1.5.2/* srclib/apr/
mv -v ../apr-util-1.5.4/* srclib/apr-util/


./configure --enable-mods-shared=all \     <---Perhaps the most important position of all.
            --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 \
            --with-mpm=prefork \
            --with-pcre=/usr/local/bin/pcre-config \
            --with-included-apr \
            --with-z=/usr/local/lib \
            --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl/lib \
            --with-sslport=443 \
            --with-port=80 \
            && make && make install && ./httpd -l && ./httpd -M
cd ~/downloads/
sleep 5
```

This fails when done as one option per line, but works like this.

```
./configure --enable-mods-shared=all --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --with-mpm=prefork --with-pcre=/usr/local/bin/pcre-config --with-included-apr --with-z=/usr/local/lib --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl/lib --with-sslport=443 --with-port=80 && make && make install && ./httpd -l && ./httpd -M
```